# How to install SELinux on SLES 15-SP1?

Tags: selinux, sles, zypper

How do I install SELinux on SLES 15-SP1? I havee tried using YaST2, following these steps:

1. Log in to your server as root and start YaST.
2. Select Software › Software Management
3. Select View › Patterns and select the entire C/C++ Development category for installation.

I can't get past Step 3 because there is no View Tab to select!

[YaST Control Center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPhLa.png)
[Software Management](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h268s.png)

Is there a way to install SELinux with zypper?

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

it depends what you exactly mean by install selinux? Just library or selinux tools?

by using zypper you can check what selinux packages are available with

```
sudo zypper se selinux
```

and then pick what you want and install it with (replace <> part):

```
sudo zypper in <packages you want>
```